# Java JDBC: Reply.fill()

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I get the following exception at times:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][3.50.152] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
>   or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill().  Message: Connection reset. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

The problem is that, the code executes successfully for quite some time and then suddenly I get this exception. However it runs perfrectly when I run the code again.

Could some one please tell me what could be wrong and provide me some pointers to resolve this.

Comment: Please refer this link as well http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21962086  and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21600160

Answer (score 5):

This is a sign of not properly closing/releasing JDBC resources. You need to acquire **and** close all JDBC resources in the shortest possible scope, i.e. you need to close them in the reversed order in the `finally` block of the `try` block of the very same method block as you've acquired them. E.g.

```
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
    // ...
} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

If you don't close them properly as soon as possible, the DB will take it in own hands sooner or later and your application may break sooner or later as you encountered yourself.

To improve connecting performance, make use of a connection pool --you still need to acquire and close them in the same manner as here above though! It's now just the connection pool implementation which under the hoods worries about *actually* closing the connection or not.

Comment: Hopefully the try-with-resources block in Java 7 will help alleviate some of this in the future. Although there is a part of me that shutters with dread about allowing developers to get away with not cleaning up resources. I fear it could lead to sloppy development. And then what happens if those developers have to work on pre-JRE 7 code? Just thinking out loud in response to your answer. But definitely ++ on the answer.

Comment: @Chris: definitely ARM will help a lot in reducing the `close()`-in-`finally` boilerplate. However, you could also go for JPA which in turn reduces the whole JDBC boilerplate to an oneliner.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know of any articles on JPA vs pure JDBC. I guess I'm coming from experience where layers of abstraction have sometimes made our application worse and harder to debug. I found pure JDBC pretty simple (at least when working with just pure SQL strings). I can see where it would work better with Objects. And it handles the resource closing for you?

Comment: None comes to mind. Working through some basic JPA tutorials must give good insights though. E.g. http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html and http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/. Yes, it transparently handles closing (and also the transactional stuff with `begin()` and `commit()` when you do it in an EJB).

Comment: When I see answer from BalusC, I just accept it as a source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

we also recently faces this issue, and it was due to confusing AND OR clauses along with a and rownum < clause. Putting braces at the right places solved it.

Comment: this post shud be a comment , not an answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your connection is timing out.  I'm not really where the problem is though.  It might be with the connection to your db server.  I'm sorry I cant help you more, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I seems this can be caused by
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC63952

At least for us it is.

Check your db2diag.log for `ZRC=0x8005006D=-2147155859=SQLE_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has been built and saved in component specific
control
block."` error messages when you get such disconnections.

Later this week we plan to upgrade to DB2 9.7 FixPack 3a -- will write back if that helped.